# Disable "inline window" in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm not sure what it's called, which is why I'm having such a hard time finding the setting. When I click on some keywords, a window inside of my window sometimes pops up. I'm not sure if this is a VS feature or ReSharper but googling around does not seem to help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the "peek" window, used for [Peek Definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn160178.aspx), amongst other things. It can actually be really useful, allowing quite a lot of navigation and editing without having to leave your current context.

But what you're seeing is the Productivity Power Tools "Click to Peek Definition" feature. When you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click on a symbol, it will navigate to the definition inside a peek window. See the description in [the features page](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace).

You can disable it in Tools > Options > Productivity Power Tools > Other Extensions > Ctrl Click shows definitions in Peek.